# Triple monitors with Mac Book Pro (earlier 2011)

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I've never setup dual or triple monitors ever. 
If I had a PC I would working something out, however, on a Mac Book Pro, not sure how.

I'm aware of `tripleHead2Go` or perhaps other adapters can be used.

Since the aspect ratio of the Mac Book Pro (earlier 2011) is 16:10, I would prefer to found a monitor like that as well.

I found this one:
http://www.samsung.com/ie/business/business-products/business-monitor/performance/LS24C45KBW/EN

My questions:

The default monitor resolution seems to point at: 1920x1200.
Is this overkill, since my laptop has 1680x1050?

The monitor support has no drivers for MAC, is this an issue, or should the adapter have those drivers and we are ok?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitors do not need drivers, so any screen would work.  Also, 1680x1050 is just the resolution the built-in display.  That doesn't mean it's the only resolution it can show. If you bought an external screen that supports 1920x1200, then the thunderbolt port on your Mac will output to it at its native resolution.  It doesn't even have to be 16x10. You could buy a 16x9 1920x1080 resolution display and it'd still work at the native resolution. You really have a lot of freedom there.

Now, regarding hooking up three of them...
Most multi-head solutions hook up either via a USB port, or will drive multiple screens from a DVI or DisplayPort connection (i.e. the Matrox TripleHead2Go)

In the case of USB ports, the screens will be slow and unsuitable for gaming (if that's important to you).  It will also need a driver that specifically supports Macs.

In the case of the DVI/DisplayPort solutions, those will appear as a single, gigantic monitor to the computer.  The screens are divided out in software, but strictly speaking, Mac-compatible software isn't a requirement. The good news is that the performance is far superior to USB. The bad news is that you're limited to the number of pixels your Mac can physically drive from that one DisplayPort, which is only 4080x768 (that's 1360x768 per screen).

Now, if you're OK with only TWO external screens (using your Mac's screen as the 3rd), then you could get 1920x1280 out of each screen using that Matrox TripleHead2Go.

If you want native resolution on all 3 displays with decent performance, your only option is Apple's Thunderbolt display -- for *only* $1000 a pop!

```
EDIT
```

Looks like I was wrong. I just looked at the product page for the Thunderbolt display and you can only chain two of them.  The TripleHead2Go is the only 3-display solution then.